# Maven - /test/classes isn't directory - Error

Tags: maven, pom.xml, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-module-package

I'm trying to make

```
mvn clean package
```

in a project that has this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.alfdev.alfresco</groupId>
    <artifactId>create-link-share</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>create-link-share AMP project</name>
    <packaging>amp</packaging>
    <description>Manages the lifecycle of the create-link-share AMP (Alfresco Module Package)</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.alfresco.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-sdk-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- 
       | SDK properties have sensible defaults in the SDK parent,
       | but you can override the properties below to use another version. 
       | For more available properties see the alfresco-sdk-parent POM. 
       -->
    <properties>
        <!-- Defines the alfresco edition to compile against. Allowed values are [org.alfresco|org.alfresco.enterprise]--> 
        <alfresco.groupId>org.alfresco</alfresco.groupId>
        <!-- Defines the alfresco version to compile against -->
        <alfresco.version>5.0.d</alfresco.version>
        <app.log.root.level>WARN</app.log.root.level>
        <alfresco.data.location>alf_data_dev</alfresco.data.location>
        <!-- Defines the target WAR artifactId to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch
        .    | Allowed values: alfresco | share. Defaults to a repository AMP, but could point to your foundation WAR -->
        <alfresco.client.war>share</alfresco.client.war>
        <!-- Defines the target WAR groupId to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch
        .    | Could be org.alfresco | org.alfresco.enterprise or your corporate groupId -->
        <alfresco.client.war.groupId>org.alfresco</alfresco.client.war.groupId>
        <!-- Defines the target WAR version to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch -->
        <alfresco.client.war.version>5.0.d</alfresco.client.war.version>
        <!-- This controls which properties will be picked in src/test/properties for embedded run -->
        <env>local</env>
    </properties>

    <!-- Here we realize the connection with the Alfresco selected platform 
        (e.g.version and edition) -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- This will import the dependencyManagement for all artifacts in the selected Alfresco version/edition
                (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) 
                NOTE: You still need to define dependencies in your POM, but you can omit version as it's enforced by this dependencyManagement. NOTE: It defaults 
                to the latest version this SDK pom has been tested with, but alfresco version can/should be overridden in your project's pom -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>alfresco-platform-distribution</artifactId>
                <version>${alfresco.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <!-- Following dependencies are needed for compiling Java code in src/main/java; 
         <scope>provided</scope> is inherited for each of the following; 
         for more info, please refer to alfresco-platform-distribution POM -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- This repository is only needed to retrieve Alfresco parent POM. 
        NOTE: This can be removed when/if Alfresco will be on Maven Central 
        
        NOTE: The repository to be used for Alfresco Enterprise artifacts is
        https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/private/. Please check
        with Alfresco Support to get credentials to add to your ~/.m2/settings.xml
        if you are a Enterprise customer or Partner  
        -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>alfresco-public</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>alfresco-public-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.alfresco.maven.plugin
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            alfresco-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.1.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>set-version</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.codehaus.mojo
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            build-helper-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.8,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>
                                                add-test-resource
                                            </goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

But I obtain the error:

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building create-link-share AMP project 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-sdk-requirements) @ create-link-share ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- alfresco-maven-plugin:1.1.1:set-version (default-set-version) @ create-link-share ---
[INFO] Added timestamp to version - 1.0.0.1510150908
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ create-link-share ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/p/Documentos/alfresco-share-create-link-v1.0.0/create-link-share.amp_FILES/META-INF/maven/com.alfdev.alfresco/create-link-share/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/p/Documentos/alfresco-share-create-link-v1.0.0/create-link-share.amp_FILES/META-INF/maven/com.alfdev.alfresco/create-link-share/src/main/amp
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ create-link-share ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ create-link-share ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ create-link-share ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) @ create-link-share ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- alfresco-maven-plugin:1.1.1:amp (default-amp) @ create-link-share ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.305 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-15T09:08:19+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/259M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.alfresco.maven.plugin:alfresco-maven-plugin:1.1.1:amp (default-amp) on project create-link-share: Error creating JAR: /home/p/Documentos/alfresco-share-create-link-v1.0.0/create-link-share.amp_FILES/META-INF/maven/com.alfdev.alfresco/create-link-share/target/classes isn't a directory. -> [Help 1]
```

How can I solve that? I'm trying to run this project:

> https://github.com/skomarica/alfresco-share-create-link

the create-link-share in this case.

Please, help me.

EDIT: with the command

> mvn clean package

this creates /target/test-classes and not /target/classes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it trying to find test classes for Share and it is not able to find that directory in alfresco share project as there are not test classes created.

You can use following command to skip execution of test classes.

```
mvn package -DskipTests=true
```

Comment: I tried this but got the same error. This is also more of a workaround since it may be required to run tests while running a build.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your project doesn't have any sources to compile.

It is inconsistent that with no resources and source code and no test resources and test source code you end up with a /test-classes but no /classes.  The only differency I can see is that the resource plugin skips non-existing directories thus maybe not creating the directory.

I'd file this as an issue.

Comment: If the root of your project is  /home/p/Documentos/alfresco-share-create-link-v1.0.0/create-link-share.amp_FILES/META-INF/maven/com.alfdev.alfresco/create-link-share.

Comment: I don't know... I have only the maven in this local... but the code are before this... I don't know how to compile this structure. If is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want ignore execution alfresco-maven-plugin:1.1.1:amp, try this

```
<pluginExecution>
   <pluginExecutionFilter>
      <groupId>
         org.alfresco.maven.plugin
      </groupId>
      <artifactId>
         alfresco-maven-plugin
      </artifactId>
      <versionRange>
         [1.1.1,)
      </versionRange>
      <goals>
         <goal>amp</goal>
      </goals>
   </pluginExecutionFilter>
   <action>
      <ignore></ignore>
   </action>
</pluginExecution>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and got it to work by restarting my computer and running the build right after. After restarting the `target` folder was gone. Running a maven build created a new `target` folder with all the right JARs in place.